# nginx - access denied for static content on Windows

Tags: windows, nginx

I have installed nginx (openresty/1.13.6.2) as a reverse proxy for different services including Grafana (works well for over a year now).

Now I wanted to serve PDF documents via nginx, so that I can create links from Grafana dashboard to documentation for operations teams.
I am on a Windows 10 box (can't change this) and I am not able to successfully serve the static PDF files via nginx. I have some experience in setting up nginx as reverse proxy, or html webserver on linux boxes (have done this several times), but on Windows now I am facing issues. Whenever I try to access/download the files via http I get a "403 Forbidden" issue.
nginx runs as a service - user "SYSTEM"

I have tried to set the permissions on the folder to the same user of nginx, but nginx is running anyway as "SYSTEM" user under windows, so it should have full access to the folder. I have checked [Access denied to Nginx folder with folders and files not being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580037/access-denied-to-nginx-folder-with-folders-and-files-not-being-created) but it seems to be an upstream service issue.

The autoindex works, it shows the list of available PDF files, but whenever I click on a file, I end up with the error.

Following snippet shows my nginx config

```
server {
        listen       8080 ssl;     
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl_certificate      certificates\TEST.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  certificates\TEST.key;
        location /grafana/ {
            ....
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }
        location /public/doc/ {
            autoindex on;
            include    mime.types;
            autoindex_format html;          
        }
    }
```

In windows PDF files are located under ./html/public/doc under the nginx directory.

This is the log entry in error.log:

```
[error] 547220#547264: *320 CreateFile() "./html/public/doc/document.pdf" failed (5: Access is denied), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET /public/doc/document.pdf HTTP/1.1"
```

I would like to get the PDF files "downloadble" but I get access denied to the files.

After the comments I edited the server block, to contain the root directory (absolute Path):

```
server {
        listen       8080 ssl;     
        server_name  localhost;
        root D:\software\nginx\html;
        ssl_certificate      certificates\TEST.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  certificates\TEST.key;
        location /grafana/ {
            ....
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }
        location /public/doc/ {
            autoindex on;
            include    mime.types;
            autoindex_format html;          
        }
    }
```

Further update:

I updated the server block to:

```
    server {
        listen       8080 ssl;     
        server_name  localhost;
        root "D:/software/nginx/html";
        ssl_certificate      certificates\TEST.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  certificates\TEST.key;
        location /grafana/ {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }
        location /public/doc {
            alias "D:/software/nginx/html/public/doc";
            autoindex on;
            include    mime.types;
            autoindex_format html;
        }

        location /public/images  {
            rewrite  ^/public/images/(.*) /$1 break;
            root "D:/data/images";
            add_header        Cache-Control public;
            add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
            expires           1s;
        }
    }
```

And I am getting now the error with the correct path to the file:

```
[error] 1628392#1627684: *14 CreateFile() "D:/software/nginx/html/public/doc/Test.pdf" failed (5: Access is denied), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET /public/doc/Tausch_QR_Cam.pdf HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.x.x:8080", referrer: "https://xx.xx.x.x:8080/public/doc/"
```

The directory listing in "public/doc" works, grafana works, and the image download works as well, still not able to access the PDF files :(

Update:
Apparently nginx was running under "SYSTEM" account. I thought this account has access to everything. Even changing ownership of directory/files from "admin" to "SYSTEM" didn't help.
What helped: changing user for the nginx service from "SYSTEM" to "admin" like below (german version). I don't exactly know why, but now it works (Files owned by "SYSTEM", "admin" has full access, nginx runs under "admin" account).
[image]
So the issue is solved, even if I don't know if solved correctly.

Comment: please attach your full code , you seems edit it , i can't help without see it all

Comment: Hi, which code do you mean - nginx.conf?

Comment: location /public/doc/ { have no root , and you not set root for server , how it will defined  ?

Comment: Ok, I have defined no root anywhere. But directoy listening works for the correct directory. It shows the files which are available in the directory. I tried with root ./html; and root html; but there is no change in behaviour. For sake of completenes, here the top part of conf:

Comment: root , mean full path of main folder  like /home/www/

Comment: Hi, sorry - today I tried to add the root to the server block. There is no change in behaviour, and as I said - the directory listing works fine, I can see all documents, but as soon as I click, there comes the "403" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing user for the nginx service from "SYSTEM" to "admin" like below (german version). I don't exactly know why, but now it works (Files owned by "SYSTEM", "admin" has full access, nginx runs under "admin" account). See latest updates in question.

Comment: [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to the rescue.